# Merging interfaces in namespace typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, namespaces

I'm working on a project and I'm struggling with namespace merging.
I have the below structure

```
// file a.d.ts
declare namespace A{
    interface IA{
       bar()
    }
    interface IB{
       //..stuff
    }
}
declare const foo: A.IA;
export = foo;
export as namespace foo;
```

When I import the above namespace in myfile.ts and try to access bar() it works fine.

```
// myfile.ts
import * as foo from 'a'
foo.bar() //works fine
```

Now I have another file b.d.ts, in which I want to add some more stuff to the existing namespace A

```
//file b.d.ts
declare namespace A{
    interface IA{
       function bar2()
    }
}
```

Since there are no top-level imports/exports in b.d.ts file, shouldn't it run at the global scope and merge both the IA interfaces?
But I cant see the bar2() function in my myfile.ts

```
import * as foo from 'a'
console.log(foo); // output has only bar1() and no bar2()
```

I want a way to add the bar2() function to the IA interface in b.d.ts file. Can someone help me out with this

Thanks

Comment: Everything declared in a module is scoped to that module. If there is a global with the same name as something declared in a module, the module scoped declaration shadows it. Functions behave exactly the same way. Are you trying to describe the shape of an external library?

Comment: If I have two namespaces with same name, then aren't the interfaces supposed to merge?

Comment: I have export statements in my a.d.ts so does that mean that the interfaces in A namespace are not available at the global scope? If yes, then how do I add more functions in the interface IA from some other file?